# my onsubmit cant get value in my form

Tags: javascript, php

I have 2 iframes.

Here is my function:

```
<script>
  function changeLink(link) {
    parent.iframe_a2.location=link;
  }
</script>
```

I have this in my form:

```
<form name="search" method="POST" action="select1WSearch.php" 
target="iframe_a" onsubmit="changeLink('select2WSearch.php')">
<input type="text" name="find" />
```

and they have same code in next page like this:

```
$find = ($_POST['find']) ? $_POST['find'] : $_GET['find'];
```

The problem is in my `action="select1WSearch.php"` when submitted it CAN get value  in  `textbox name="find"` BUT my `onsubmit="changeLink('select2WSearch.php')">` CANT get the value of that. Help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/74C8U/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried returning true in the function? By not returning a value, you return undefined, which is `falsey` (when casted to boolean it is false) and may signal to the browser that the `onsubmit` check should fail and thus not allow submission of the form.

What browser(s) are you using to test this?

Answer (score 0):

You do not perform `POST`. You change the location of an iframe, which instructs the browser to load a new page, using `GET`; this action does not send the form to another URL.

What you can do is to get the value in `find` edit box, and pass it to the iframe with something like that:

```
parent.iframe_a2.location = link + "?find=" + find.value;
```

This is pseudo-code.

Comment: i var dump find in `select2WSearch.php` but the value now is `string 'undefined' (length=9)`

Comment: @RANRAN You have to find `input` element in the DOM, its `name` attribute must be equal to `find`, and then you take `value` attribute of such `input` element. It is because of that point that I said it was pseudo-code rather than real/working one.